# geom_raster() normal distrubution

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to understand geom_raster(). As a simple example I wanted to visualize something like normal distribution as a raster. I used the following code.

```
v1 <- rnorm(n=50)
v2 <- rnorm(n=50)
v3 <- rnorm(n=50)
vs <- tibble(v1,v2,v3)
ggplot(vs, aes(v1, v2)) +
 geom_raster(aes(fill = v3))
```

I ended up with the following:

[image]

I was expected something like the following image

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`geom_raster` is for when you have one value for each rectangle. I think you're looking for something like `geom_bin2d`, but you'll need more data, and you likely won't get any data for areas far from the modes:

```r
ggplot(data.frame(v1 = rnorm(10000), 
                  v2 = rnorm(10000)), 
       aes(x = v1, y = v2)) + 
    geom_bin2d()
```

[image]

If the sharpness of the corners bothers, you, `geom_hex` is a nice alternative that leaves isolated points looking less pixellated and more like points. `geom_density_2d` is a common accompaniment to add contour lines.

To use `geom_raster`, you'd need something more like

```r
df <- expand.grid(v1 = seq(-2, 2, .1), v2 = seq(-2, 2, .1))
df$v3 <- dnorm(df$v1) * dnorm(df$v2) 

ggplot(df, aes(v1, v2, fill = v3)) + geom_raster()
```

[image]

`geom_contour` can be used as an accompaniment to show contour lines. It requires a `z` aesthetic instead of `fill`, but otherwise works like `geom_raster`.

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks!